# C++ trying to read a file and output to a different text file

Tags: c++

I have this school project I wanted to modify.  I wanted to be able to read from a file and output to a different from after decoding the original file.  Everything compiles fine but when I open the new file there is only the last word that was decoded instead of the entire sentence.  I think  it has to do with the while (!inFS.eof()) loop but I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you. Here is the code.

```
// Secret Message App
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<char> normalV(26);
    vector<char> cipherV(26);
    string toDec = "";
    string beenDec = "";
    string usrInptOptn = "default";
    ifstream inFS;
    ofstream outFS;    
    string filename;

    // Vector for Message letters and Cipher Symbols
    normalV.at(0) = 'a'; cipherV.at(0) = '!';
    normalV.at(1) = 'b'; cipherV.at(1) = '^';
    normalV.at(2) = 'c'; cipherV.at(2) = '&';
    normalV.at(3) = 'd'; cipherV.at(3) = '*';
    normalV.at(4) = 'e'; cipherV.at(4) = '@';
    normalV.at(5) = 'f'; cipherV.at(5) = '(';
    normalV.at(6) = 'g'; cipherV.at(6) = ')';
    normalV.at(7) = 'h'; cipherV.at(7) = '-';
    normalV.at(8) = 'i'; cipherV.at(8) = '#';
    normalV.at(9) = 'j'; cipherV.at(9) = '_';
    normalV.at(10) = 'k'; cipherV.at(10) = '=';
    normalV.at(11) = 'l'; cipherV.at(11) = '+';
    normalV.at(12) = 'm'; cipherV.at(12) = '[';
    normalV.at(13) = 'n'; cipherV.at(13) = '{';
    normalV.at(14) = 'o'; cipherV.at(14) = '$';
    normalV.at(15) = 'p'; cipherV.at(15) = ']';
    normalV.at(16) = 'q'; cipherV.at(16) = '}';
    normalV.at(17) = 'r'; cipherV.at(17) = ';';
    normalV.at(18) = 's'; cipherV.at(18) = ':';
    normalV.at(19) = 't'; cipherV.at(19) = ',';
    normalV.at(20) = 'u'; cipherV.at(20) = '%';
    normalV.at(21) = 'v'; cipherV.at(21) = '<';
    normalV.at(22) = 'w'; cipherV.at(22) = '.';
    normalV.at(23) = 'x'; cipherV.at(23) = '>';
    normalV.at(24) = 'y'; cipherV.at(24) = '/';
    normalV.at(25) = 'z'; cipherV.at(25) = '?';

    // Get secret message

        cout << "\nSpecify file to Open: example secret.txt." << endl;
        cin >> filename;
        cout << "Opening secret message file... " << filename << endl;
        inFS.open(filename.c_str());

        if (!inFS.is_open()) {
        cout << "Could not open file secret.txt.\n";
        return 1;
        }

    while (!inFS.eof()) {
        inFS >> toDec;
    } 

    while (toDec.length() == 0); 

    beenDec = toDec;

    // Loop Count Variables
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;

    // Decrypt secret message
    for (i = 0; i < toDec.size(); ++i) { // This Loop cycles for each character in the input message
        for (n = 0; n < 26; ++n) {      // This Loops the if statement 
            if (toDec.at(i) == cipherV.at(n)) { //This converts the cipher into normal letters from the "normalV" vector
                beenDec.at(i) = normalV.at(n);
            }
        }
    }

    inFS.close(); // Done with file, so close it

    outFS.open("decrypted.txt");    
        if (!outFS.is_open()) {
        cout << "Could not open file secret.txt.\n";
        return 1;
        }
    outFS << beenDec << endl;
    outFS.close(); // Done with file, so close it       

    cout << "Decrypted message: " << beenDec << "  Has been saved to: decrypted.txt" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read the section on creating a [example]. You can cut a lot out of this code and still maintain the error, which helps us (and you) narrow down the issue.

Comment: Pop quiz: as you know, `inFS >> toDec;` replaces the entire contents of `toDec` (a `std::string`) with the next word read from `inFS`, because that's how `>>` works. Did you know that? If not, see your C++ book for more info. But if you do know that, your pop quiz will be: at the conclusion of the `while` loop, whose sole contents is this statement, what's going to be the contents of `toDec`. I'll even make it a multiple choice pop quiz: 1) The entire contents of the file, 2) the last word that was read from it.

Comment: You are reading word by word and using the last word that was read. If you put the rest of your function inside the white loop after you get the word it might work. Since I don't know your file structure.  while (!inFS.eof()) {
        inFS >> toDec; //insert the rest of the code here
    }

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct here is the error.

```
while (!inFS.eof()) {
    inFS >> toDec;
}
```

Please use the following in place of the above LOC.

```
string temp = ""; // Declaring a temp string variable wherever you want

while (inFS >> temp) {
    toDec += temp;
}
```

Now it will work.

Thanks & Regards,
Ankur Gupta

Comment: that works but the sentence from the secret.txt file has all the spaces taken out of it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Because, you are not writing any other character that are not present in the vectors i.e. other than (a - z).

Answer (score 0):

```
    cout << "\nSpecify file to Open: example secret.txt." << endl;
    cin >> filename;
    cout << "Opening secret message file... " << filename << endl;
    inFS.open(filename.c_str());

    if (!inFS.is_open()) {
         cout << "Could not open file secret.txt.\n";
         return 1;
    }
    outFS.open("decrypted.txt");    
    if (!outFS.is_open()) {
         cout << "Could not open file secret.txt.\n";
         return 1;
    }

    while (inFS >> toDec) {
    beenDec = toDec;
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;

    // Decrypt secret message
    for (i = 0; i < toDec.size(); ++i) { // This Loop cycles for each character in the input message
        for (n = 0; n < 26; ++n) {      // This Loops the if statement 
            if (toDec.at(i) == cipherV.at(n)) { //This converts the cipher into normal letters from the "normalV" vector
                beenDec.at(i) = normalV.at(n);
            }
        }
    }
     outFS << beenDec << endl;
     cout << "Decrypted message: " << beenDec << "  Has been saved to: decrypted.txt" << endl;
} 

inFS.close(); // Done with file, so close it
outFS.close(); // Done with file, so close it       
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Probably something like this due to a lack of knowledge of what's in your file.

Comment: the secret file stores a few sentences or a phrase that needs to be decoded to a decrypted file.

Comment: is it line by line decoding or just a single word or the entire thing.

Comment: instead of using the while loop why not use std::istreambuf_iterator instead.